# port scanner always returns no available open ports

Tags: c++, port-scanning

When I run this code, it always returns no available open ports. How do I solve this?

```
for(y=1; y<20000; y++ ) {
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    Info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPaddress);
    Info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Info.sin_port = htons(y);

    x = connect (sock, NULL, NULL);

    if(x != SOCKET_ERROR ){
        cout << "Port" << y <<  "- OPEN ! " << endl;
    }

    closesocket(sock);
}

WSACleanup();

cout << "Port scan has finished " << endl;
system("pause");
```

Comment: How do you know that that there are no available ports? Can you provide the output that you get?

Comment: i mean..  i only show to the output when port is opened . when the port is not opened it will not show anything. but,  No matter what IP address I try it always returns no open ports.

Comment: Add a call to WSAGetLastError for understanding what is the error, then the error code should tell you what is the problem. It could be unrelated to the port ike for example if you provide an address that does not exist in your network.

Comment: Try actually passing `Info` to `connect`. Do you think it will divine it out? Don't forget the third argument either.